# If $X$ and $Y$ not independent, does it mean that $Y=f(X)$?

Tags: probability

1. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two random variable (on the same probability space). We suppose that they are not independent. Does it mean that $Y=f(X)$ for some Borel function $f$?
2. Same, if they are independent, does it mean that there is no Borel function $f$ s.t. $Y=f(X)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 2): $Y=f(X)$ with $f$ measurable implies that $X$ is indepedent of itself, hence constant. So if you exclude constants the we cannot
 write $Y$ as $f(X)$.

1) No. If $\{X,Z\}$ is i.i.d. and non-constant then it is rarely true that $X$ and $Y=X+Z$ are independent. When they are not independent we cannot write $X+Z=f(X)$ because this would imply $Z=f(X)-X$ which is false.  For a specific example take $\{X,Z\}$ is i.i.d.  with standard normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Last thing, if $Y\in \boldsymbol (X)$, then $Y$ and $X$ are necessarily dependent ?

Comment: @user657607 What do you mean  by $Y \in (X)$?

Comment: Sorry, if $Y\in \sigma (X)$.

Comment: @user657607 If $Y \in \sigma(X)$ and $X,Y$ are independent then  $Y$ would be independent of itself, hence a constant. So, barring constants, we can say that the variables are necessarily dependent.